# App service plan File system storage quotas

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-file-share

Azure function on the consumption plan has 1 GB storage for File system storage. Currently, the storage gets filled up when we run all the master data from the source. It gets filled up by log files.

[image]

What does this mean? Will the logs be deleted automatically, or does it stop logging now because it's full? Will the service stop working because the quota is full?

Answer (score 1):

@Aram Yako You will need to delete your log files as they will not delete automatically. Not deleting the log files can cause issues for your Function app if you were to run out of space. The action is on you as the owner of the function app to ensure logging does not consume all of your storage space and logs are deleted after they are not needed anymore.

The good news is that there are a number of items that can reduce the size of your logs. Some of these items are reducing your log level to only error or warning levels.

To further understand options to help, reduce the log space needed, please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#solutions-with-high-volume-of-telemetry) for additional suggestions.